# Join or Group By VARIANT column: a good practice?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

We need to deduplicate a recordset (hundreds of millions of rows) in Snowflake and the engine allows you to `group by` or `join` using the variant column directly, but (obviously) it's a resource consuming process. The problem is that the schema of JSON content of the `VARIANT` column can change without prior notice so we can't simply extract the required fields (or all fields) for the deduplication SQL statements (which is much much faster).

Does anybody know if executing a join or group by using a VARIANT column is inherently wrong? or is it possible that it would lead to wrong results?

Regards,
Babak.

Comment: Are you joining on the full json column `a.json_column = b.json_column` or on extracted values from the json like `a.json_column:ID = b.json_column:ID`?

Comment: Joining on the full JSON column.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the performance implications. I just want to make sure that I'll not be running a SQL statement which might return incorrect values (e.g. because of hash collision or...).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing "inherently" wrong that I know of here. It won't scale well to large tables, or very large variant columns though.

When data is parsed into a variant, SnowFlake does do some processing on them for the purpose of indexing, null handling, and performance. Notably, Variant nulls, the null value inside of the JSON, can be compared as equal to itself, unlike SQL NULLS. Also, data types like numbers and dates are stored as strings when they are within a variant, and use string equality. So if your data sources handle data types differently you might be able to see a scenario where `2020-01-01 12:00:00.00` is treated as not equal to `2020-01-01 12:00:00`, but I haven't tested this.

This processing is why you noticed (in a separate comment) that `{"a":1,"b":2}` is stored the same way as `{"b": 2, "a": 1}` and thus they are "equal to" each other. So that could technically count as a "false positive", joining when you don't expect them to be equal. But as far as I know, this processing is consistent and you shouldn't get false negatives.

Answer (score 1):

In my tests it seems to work fine -- unless you want the order of items in arrays to not matter.  If it's internally storing hash's for objects then it might be reasonably performant.  Lastly note the lack of truthiness for variants: `select 1='1', 1::variant = '1'::variant;` returns `TRUE,`FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks, fortunately 1) the JSON blobs don't contain any arrays, and 2) I'm comparing variant against variant. So there's no casting (implicit or explicit) involved. I found it interesting that if the order of fields inside the JSON changes, Snowflake can detect that and doesn't simply compare a string representation of the JSON blob; i.e. {"a":1,"b":2} is declared equal (from a join operation's perspective) to {"b": 2, "a": 1}
My only concern is that whether the internal representation of the Variant might lead to unexpected results, if it's used in an equality predicate.

Comment: I don't see a mention of variant/object/array equality in the docs.  For an authoritative answer I recommend contacting support -- they're very responsive.  Note you can also cast a VARIANT to TEXT and then compare -- in my tests the results are consistent.  You could also define a javascript UDF to do the comparison -- In javascript a common convention for comparing objects is to call JSON.stringify() and compare the strings.